# Unzipping big archive ( > 1 GB) using PHP

Tags: php, unzip, php-ziparchive

So I have this program which needs to unzip some really big zip files. Each will be between 1 to 2 GB in size. My zip program works without any issues in smaller size files (upto few hundred MB everything is fine). But when the archives are bigger, the program unzips, but stalls execution and does not continue. I have increased mem size and exec time, but to no avail. My code is:

```
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','3000M');

writeLog("Starting to extract...");

$zip = new ZipArchive();
if ($zip->open($zipFile) === TRUE)
{
    $zip->extractTo(ZIP_DIR);
    $zip->close();
}
else
{
    writeLog('There was an error while unzipping');
}
processZipFile();
```

When I run this the log says: "Starting to extract..."

It never gives me the error: "There was an error while unzipping"

When I go to the unzip folder and check it, I can see that the archive was unzipped successfully but it never calls `processZipFile()`. In fact even if I write an `echo` in its place it never gets executed.

I am running this script from command line using `php unzip.php`. My script might need to run in both windows and linux so I am not sure about using the underlying OS unzip functionality inside a `system()` call...

Comment: What about not using PHP? Just use bash to start an unzipping program, and then launch PHP via CLI.

Comment: @TJHeuvel I had thought about this, but unfortunately this script might need to run in both Windows and Linux (I am developing in Windows btw) and so I do not want to use the underlying OS method...

Comment: Have you monitored your script's memory usage? It might exceed your allowed 3GB

Comment: @Hubro I haven't done that, will check. However I am not sure if I will be able to allocate more than 3GB...

Comment: is display_errors and error_reporting enabled? Maybe there is a failure that is suppressed